# Many to Many Relationship control in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am looking for a set of controls (Client side or Server Side) using which I can manage a many to many relationship in ASP.NET.

For instance, a course can be opted by many students and a student can have many courses enrolled.

I would appreciate if someone can guide me through which set of controls I should go for. Currently, I am using a two listboxes places parrallel to each other and clicking on one selects the related data in the second and vice versa. But I am looking for more User friendly UI options.

Thanks  in advance.
PS: If it is a third party control, I would prefer to go for Telerik.

Comment: Well, basically even in a many to many relationship, you'll be editing only 1 thing at a time : adding/dropping courses from a given student or adding/dropping students from a given course. I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: That's true. I'll be doing editing/deleting/adding one item at a time but the UI matters. I do not want to have that User Interface its quite a traditional way to do that.

Comment: @Bartdude: For instance a Parent Child grid or a tree can be used to display the students enrolled in a course. I am looking for such options.

Comment: So you should simply look for (or develop) a nice list edition control. Finding one shouldn't be that hard. But I'm still not sure to understand if you need editing functionality or if you just want to display data ? If that's only for display then definitely a user control with some HTML should do the trick...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going for parent child grid, its easier for me to display/edit/add as well. But I was just taking my time to find a better solution than parent child grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic_admin/form_controls.html
to get an idea of what you can choose.

Possibly, i would have used a Drop down with auto search and a check box list for the other part.

Comment: Hi Ashish,
Thanks for the this wonderfull link. I would prefer not to go for the traditional dropdown/listbox and checkbox list combination.

Thanks.